# Query to get top 10 items per item group

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to make a query whereby I can generate a list for the top 10 items per item group per. 
It is for a supermarket chain whereby all items are divided into item groups. E.g Rice, Salt etc. There will be different brands of Rice and Different brands for Salt.

I need to get the data from a SAP Business One Table (MS SQL Server 2008)

Sample results from the Item Group table, OITB

`SELECT * FROM OITB` (showing first two columns for item groups)

```
ItmsGrpCod  ItmsGrpNam
101         RICE
102         SALT
103         SUGAR
104         FROZEN VEGETABLE
```

This returns 224 results.

`SELECT * FROM OITB` (showing first two columns for items)

```
ItemCode    ItemName          ItmsGrpCod    
2001        A1 GRAIN RICE     101
2001        ASHA BRAND RICE   101
2003        PISHORI RICE      101
2004        B7 GRADE RICE     101
2019        JIM SALT          102
2020        KAYKAY SALT       102
```

I also have this query below that gets the top 10 items but I have to specify the Item group code (field ItmsGrpCod)

```
SELECT TOP 100 T0.ItemCode, T0.ItemName, T1.DocDate, T6.Price AS COST,P3.Price AS POS,
((P3.Price-T6.Price)/T6.Price)*100 AS [Markup %], T2.OnHand, SUM(T1.Quantity) 
AS Quantity, SUM(T1.LineTotal) AS SALES,T6.Price *SUM(T1.Quantity) AS [Sales 
Cost],SUM(T1.LineTotal) - T6.Price *SUM(T1.Quantity) AS [GP Amount],
(SUM(T1.LineTotal) - T6.Price *SUM(T1.Quantity))/(T6.Price *SUM(T1.Quantity))
*100 as [GP %],T3.WhsName FROM OITM T0
INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T0.ItemCode = T1.ItemCode 
INNER JOIN OITW T2 ON T0.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode 
INNER JOIN OWHS T3 ON T1.WhsCode = T3.WhsCode 
INNER JOIN OINV T4 ON T1.DocEntry = T4.DocEntry 
INNER JOIN OITB T5 ON T0.ItmsGrpCod = T5.ItmsGrpCod 
INNER JOIN ITM1 T6 ON T0.ItemCode = T6.ItemCode  
INNER JOIN (SELECT P1.ItemCode, P2.Price FROM OITM P1 
INNER JOIN ITM1 P2 ON P1.ItemCode=P2.ItemCode WHERE 
P2.PriceList='1') P3 ON P3.ItemCode=T0.ItemCode WHERE T6.PriceList ='2' 
AND T2.WhsCode = '01' AND T1.WhsCode = '01' AND T4.DocDate 
= CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE() -1, 101)
AND T0.ItmsGrpCod = '103'  --(Item Group Code)
GROUP BY T0.ItemCode, T0.ItmsGrpCod, T0.ItemName, T1.DocDate, T6.Price, P3.Price, ((P3.Price-T6.Price)
/NULLIF(T6.Price, 0))* 100, T2.OnHand, T3.WhsName ORDER BY Quantity DESC
```

What I need is a query that will first get all the Item Group Codes from OITB and store them temporarily in an array, and then run the 2nd query for each Item Group Code. Assuming that there are at least 10 items in each item group, the query should return 2240 results. However, some item group have less than 10 items. I have really not used arrays in SQl so how would I build a query to get what I want? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this statement will help:

```
Create table OITB (itmsGrpCod int ,ItmsGrpNam varchar(30) )

insert into OITB select 101,'RICE'
insert into OITB select 102,'SALT'
insert into OITB select 103,'SUGAR'
insert into OITB select 104,'FROZEN VEGETABLE'



Create table Item (ItemCode int ,ItemName varchar(20),ItmsGrpCod int )

insert into Item select 1011,'A RICE',101
insert into Item select 1012,'B RICE',101
insert into Item select 1013,'C RICE',101
insert into Item select 1014,'D RICE',101
insert into Item select 1015,'E RICE',101
insert into Item select 1016,'F RICE',101
insert into Item select 1017,'G RICE',101
insert into Item select 1018,'H RICE',101
insert into Item select 1019,'I RICE',101
insert into Item select 10111,'J RICE',101
insert into Item select 10112,'K RICE',101
insert into Item select 10113,'L RICE',101
insert into Item select 10114,'M RICE',101
insert into Item select 1020,'A SALT',102
insert into Item select 1021,'B SALT',102
insert into Item select 1042,'C SALT',102





WITH recordsList
AS
(
    SELECT  Item.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItmsGrpNam
                                ORDER BY Item.itmsGrpCod ) rn
    FROM    OITB
  inner join 
  Item on OITB.ItmsGrpCod=Item.ItmsGrpCod
)
SELECT  *
FROM    recordsList
WHERE   rn <= 10
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ravi Singh. This will not bring the expected results as in each ItmsGrpNam is unique to a specific grouping. E.g. In you answer above, Rice in OITB would only have the item group code 101. And not any other. You will have different types of rice (brands) under the same item group code IE. 101. If I have a hundred groups each with a hundred items, the query should return the top 10 of each group, IE 1000 results. Hope I am explaining myself. I have edited the question.

Comment: I understand this. So, you will have table with 'brands' and and ItmGrpCode.Use join of these two table in CTE and that should help.

Comment: OK. Thanks. But how exactly do I do that?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just change the inner join because you are joining the same tables. Then I accept.

Comment: Is this what you wanted. Kindly accept the answer, if it works for you.

Comment: I cannot see that, join is between two tables OTIB and ITEM

Answer (score 1):

I googled for OITM and OITB schemas.

I understood that you mistakenly described OITB both as group and item entity.

From my findings:

- OITB - product group
- OITM - product item
- INV1 - inventory

Hence, extending Ravi's solution, this should do the trick:

```
WITH OITB_OITM AS
(
  SELECT
    OITB.ItmsGrpCod, OITB.ItmsGrpNam,
    OITM.ItemCode, OITM.ItemName,
    INV1.Quantity,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (
      PARTITION BY OITB.ItmsGrpNam
      ORDER BY
        INV1.Quantity DESC,
        OITM.ItemName /* For clashing quantities */
    ) idx
  FROM
    OITM
      INNER JOIN INV1 ON INV1.ItemCode   = OITM.ItemCode
      INNER JOIN OITB ON OITB.ItmsGrpCod = OITM.ItmsGrpCod
)
SELECT *
FROM OITB_OITM
WHERE idx <= 10
```

Comment: Thanks Mvaraujo for your answer.